# How to save multi select value in list field in node programmatically

Tags: nodes

I need to programmatically save multi value in list text field in Node.
E.g.
 I am having multi select drop-down of language field, I am getting value in

$languages = array('English', 'French', 'English (UK)')

I need to save in node :

```
$node->field_languages[$node->language] = array();

foreach ($languages as $language){

    $node->field_languages[$node->language][]['value'] = strtolower($language);

}
```

$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving

node_save($node);

Please help me out, How to save multi select value in list field.